# How to web-scrape with querySelector and display information in a Text Widget in Flutter?

Tags: json, web-scraping, dart, flutter

I've been trying to figure this out for about two days, and I cannot for the life of me, and so i will do my best to present my question here:

So basically, what I want to do is to gather information from a website using a querySelector (example: document.querySelectorAll('td.title > a');" and then place that information in a Text widget. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing special while Scraping in Flutter vs just Dart.
Remember that anything i.e written in 100% Dart will work in Flutter.

You can follow this guide and explains the basics of scraping with Dart
https://itnext.io/write-your-first-web-scraper-in-dart-243c7bb4d05

The basic steps are:

1) Make an http request and store it in a variable

2) parse the response body with parser (imported from html/parser lib)
Now you have your entire response as html, that means you can access nodes,elements and manipulate content

3) Use document.querySelector to select the desired element. Note it takes css selector argument, also be carefull that your css selector is pointing exactly where you want to.

4) Now if you know the querySelector type you can declare or just use a var. (Declaring it's static is better option it will give access dom manipulation properties and methods)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

void getIMDBReview()async{
final response = await http.get(
          'https://m.imdb.com/title/$imdbId/reviews?ref_=m_tt_urv');
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // print(response.body);
        var document = parse(response.body);
        var reviewContent = document.querySelectorAll(
            '#reviews-container > .ipl-content-list__item > .imdb-user-review >.review-container >.content>.text');
        for(var review in reviewContent){
        print(review.text);
        }

      }
 }
```

Replace the imdbId with id and hopefully it will return all the reviews

Comment: I see! Thank you for that code snippet. This does answer a lot of my question, however there's still one thing i need to know. How would I place review.text elsewhere? In my case, in a _buildItem Widget.

Comment: Store it in a String variable and use that variable inside your build method.

Comment: How would I do this without being local tho? Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my questions btw.

Comment: You can declare the variable inside your state class and then write this function inside the class as well. Then use that variable to set values.

Comment: If I have answered your question. You can mark it solved

Comment: Yep, you're right. Marked it now. Thank you so much!

Comment: unfortunately this only works for server side scraping client side scarping cannot do with this